# Como trabajar con referencias nulas en entity framework core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Tengo un incoveniente con entity framework core 6 para manejar referencias nulas. Trabajo con database first.
Tengo una tabla Usuarios con columnas que aceptan datos nulos al momento de hacer consultas a la base de datos con EF Core me tira las siguiente exception.
**data is null. this method or property cannot be called on null values**
no se me soluciona haciendo nulleable la propiedad. ejemplo

```
public int? identificationId { get; set;}
```

Alguien sabe como trabajar esto de forma correcta en .net 6 ?

Comment: Pon como estas haciendo tu consulta, edita tu pregunta y pon la consulta que estas haciendo

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer puede haber diferencias entre la entidad y la tabla de la base de datos. Para estos casos podrías probar configurar la entidad en OnConfiguring, por ejemplo:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure StudentId as FK for StudentAddress
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasRequired(s => s.Address) 
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Student); 

}
```

Si tienes una propiedad que es requerida utilizas .HasRequired (o quizas tengas .IsRequired() que le pasas true o false) pero si acepta null no lo pondrias y deberia funcionar.

Espero haber sido de ayuda, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hola las referencias (Nulleable) ya vienen por default en .NET Core 6, si bien sabemos Microsoft anuncio esto ya hace años atrás como en el 2019 si mal no recuerdo.

Ya si por ejemplo deseas que no sea Nulleable una variable deberías armar un constructor. por ejemplo:

```
public class Client
{
  //Nulo activado
  public Client (int identification)
  {
    identificationId = identification
  }

  public int identificationId { get; set; }

}
```

Espero haber podido ayudarte! Saludos desde Panamá!